# Simulating a "Coin Tossing" Game

Tags: simulation

i was wondering if i could simulate the following Coin-tossing-game in Mathematica:

Two Persons are playing "Coin-tossing" against each other.
If one wins, he gives one Dollar to the other. Game continues until one Person has no money left.

Would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hi Joe, its doable - it would be useful for others if you could provide some code to start with. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yeah i tried some things, but i am failing at the basics right now.
I found out how to use the IF Construct in Mathematica and i think i might have to use RandomInteger[]
But i dont know how to declare Variables, for example.

Comment: In Mathematica you don't declare Variables.

Comment: something like this : `f[x_] := x + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]; 
testQ[y_] := (y > 0); NestWhileList[f, 10, testQ]` ?

Comment: Changed *throwing* to *tossing* which next to *flipping* seems a much more [standard name for the game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping).

Comment: Why did people downvote this question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say that both players start with 10 dollars. We can represent the game state with a list:

```
start = {10, 10};
```

Create a function which plays one round of the game. There are only two possible outcomes, we can use [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html) to pick randomly between them:

```
oneRound[{x_, y_}] := RandomChoice[{{x + 1, y - 1}, {x - 1, y + 1}}]
```

For example `oneRound[start]` will give either `{9, 11}` or `{11, 9}` with equal probability. By repeatedly applying the `oneRound` function to the list we can simulate the game. But we also need to stop the game when one player runs out of money. So we create another function which returns `True` if the game can continue and `False` otherwise. The condition for the game to continue is that both players have more than zero dollars:

```
gameContinues[{x_, y_}] := x > 0 && y > 0
```

To simulate a full game we need some code which starts with the list `start` and repeatedly applies the function `oneRound` as long as `gameContinues` returns `True`. As Andre suggested, we can use [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) for this:

```
result = NestWhileList[oneRound, start, gameContinues]
```

> {{10, 10}, {11, 9}, {12, 8}, {11, 9}, ..., {18, 2}, {19, 1}, {20, 0}}

To visualise the game:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[result], PlotLegends -> {"Player 1", "Player 2"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really Helpful, thanks a lot Sir Simon :)